# I'm unable to make my sprites "Flip"

Tags: actionscript, sprite

I'll start off by admitting that I am a beginner to ActionScript and I am in the process of coding my own basic arcade game (Similar to that of the old arcade game "Joust"). Whilst I have been able to code the sprite's movement I am looking to make the sprite flip to face the other way when I press the right arrow. I figured either I could try and rotate the object around its axis (Which I've tried multiple times and has proved difficult) or I could try and "Replace" the current sprite with another sprite (Which is just the sprite facing the opposite way). I've searched everywhere for a method of replacing a sprite with another sprite but to no avail. How would it be possible to give this sprite a flip effect when a certain keyCode is used?

Answer (score 1):

Try this simple code below. Here 'object' is the movieclip/sprite that you want to flip

```
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, OnKeyDown);

function OnKeyDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
{
    var uiKeyCode:uint = event.keyCode; 
    switch (uiKeyCode)
    {
        case Keyboard.LEFT :
            object.scaleX = -1; //flip
            break;
        case Keyboard.RIGHT :
            object.scaleX = 1; //unflip
            break;
    }
}
```

NOTE: If you want the movieclip to flip without any shift in its position then the movieclip must be horizontally center registered.

Tell me if this works for you.

Comment: much simpler for beginners than my solution (+1)

Comment: Yes george. But i guess matrix is faster. Not sure though

Comment: not really. scaleX uses the transformation matrix behind the scenes anyway so it's a matter of using a setter. Getters are a bit slow in as3 (slower than setters) and my version uses 2 (1 to fetch the matrix, one to check the value of `a`) and a conditional. your solution is simpler and faster in this case ;)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using as2/as3? you could flip the axis Y 180 degrees
if your using as2 you will need to either mirror the bitmap via actionScript or 
add a second bitmap that is mirrored to the display list.

```
    stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyPressedDown);

    function keyPressedDown(event:KeyboardEvent):void
    {
         var key:uint = event.keyCode;

    switch (key)
   {
    case Keyboard.LEFT :
                    myMovieClip.rotaionY = 180; // MC will be mirrored
        break;
    case Keyboard.RIGHT :
                    myMovieClip.rotaionY = 0;

 }
```

Comment: rotationY is easier to understand but it sets the movie clip in '3d mode' (uses `.transform.matrix3D` instead of `.transform.matrix`), it's actionscript 3.0 only and it works from flash player 10 upwards. using the 2D transformation matrix is slightly tougher, but not rocket science for a simple flip and works in actionscript 2.0 and works with most flash player versions (down to flash player 6 I presume)